# Angular 6 data e hora em portugues

Tags: angular

Boa tarde,
Estou começando a desenvolver uma aplicação em Angular 6, e preciso exibir na tela a data e a hora. Ja consegui apresentar ambas, mas estão no padrão americano. Como posso alterar para o padrão brasileiro?

Answer (score 6):

Consegui. Fiz o seguinte:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeBr from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
```

No import do NgModule importei tambem `LOCALE_ID`

Depois

```
registerLocaleData(localeBr, 'pt')
```

E na declaração de providers

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt' }
```

Tudo isso no modulo principal(*appmodule*)

Comment: Sim, já fiz isso em projetos aqui. Nem lembrei de colocar na resposta, achei que só queria formatar mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação oficial do Angular, você pode usar os formatos pré-definidos do DatePipe, ou se preferir, customize os seus formatos, que acredito, será o indicado pra o seu caso. Leia mais sobre o DatePipe em https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Use da seguinte forma:

```
//Classe do seu componente
class SuaClasse{
  hoje: number = Date.now();
}

//no seu template
<div>
  <p>Data e hora de hoje é {{ hoje | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}</p>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você pode usar a interpolação seguida do pipe `date`.

Exemplo no HMTL:

```
{{ variavelComAData | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}
```

Para mais detalhes consulte a [documentação do DatePipe nas docs do angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).